# how to specific rails version? i have different versions in different project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
yulong@ubuntu:~$ rails -v

Rails 3.1.0

yulong@ubuntu:~$ cd four

yulong@ubuntu:~/four$ rails -v

Rails 3.1.0.rc8

yulong@ubuntu:~/four$ cd ..

yulong@ubuntu:~$ cd z

yulong@ubuntu:~/z$ rails -v

Rails 3.1.0.rc6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to set Rails versions and not Ruby versions per project add the rails version to the Gemfile in each project folder

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: yulong@ubuntu:~$ gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command rails,
yulong@ubuntu:~$ gem list --local rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.1.0, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc6, 3.0.10)
yulong@ubuntu:~$

Comment: YuLong, you should put line `gem 'rails', '3.1.0'` into Gemfile in root of your rails project.

Answer (score 3):

Use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) on Linux/OSX and [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) on Windows

For every project(folder) you can customize ruby and rails versions. Then rvm automatically will set all gems(libraries) for every folder accordingly to your settings.

Comment: can i have more details？i can find the solution in rvm.-_-!

Comment: You mean the tutorial? Try this http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/a/Using-Rvm-Gemsets.htm. Also do not forget about gemfile in every project as it mentioned holodigm.